# How to show that this is a group isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to show that if for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, the map $f_n\colon (\mathbb{Z},+) \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z},+), x \mapsto nx$ is a group isomorphism, then $n \in \{-1,1\}$, without using anything besides the group structure. So especially I don't want to use that there are the rationals or that $\mathbb{Z} $ is an ordered set ( this would make the proof of course very trivial).

I.e. it boils down to show that if $nx=1$, then $n \in \{-1,1\}$ without using rationals or the fact that the integers are ordered.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: how can I show this without referring to anything but the group structure of $\mathbb{Z}$. I mean it is trivial to solve this over $\mathbb{Q}$ if you know that there must be something that gets mapped to $1$ or if you know that $\mathbb{Z}$ is an ordered set(by monotony) but if I don't use any of these two things, then I think it is not that easy

Comment: @MikeMiller well, that $-1$ and $1$ do it, is pretty clear, the question is rather: How do I exclude the other ones?

Comment: Ah! I misread your question. Apologies.

Comment: @XinWang maybe add something to your question that clarifies that

Comment: So are you allowed to use the fact that there is no integer $x$ such that $nx = 1$ if $n\ne \pm 1$? If not, I'm not sure how you're going to make any progress.

Comment: well, I am only allowed to use that $\mathbb{Z}$ with the addition is a group, nothing else. but yes, I think it boils down to the question if we can show this by just using that $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ is a group.

Comment: I improved the notation somewhat. You should be careful when mixing formal logic symbols and english expressions, as it tends to make the result unclear and/or downright wrong (as it was here). In fact, you should avoid the former altogether in writing (except when talking about logic), except when writing on blackboard, as in during a lecture or problem session (where it might be more important to be concise and you can just spell out anything that might be unclear), or personal notes (where you know best what you mean and what is clear for you).

Comment: And this is no accident that several people (including me) misread the question. Sorry if I come across as chastising: I used to make the same mistake as an undergraduate student, and now I believe that it is an important one to correct. Logic symbols are good for logic calculus or talking about the structure of a proof, not writing the proof itself.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are three (relatively simple) things that you must show:

- If $n\in\{-1,1\},$ then for any $j,k\in\Bbb Z,$ we have $f_n(j+k)=f_n(j)+f_n(k).$ (That is, $f_n$ is a homomorphism.)
- If $n\in\{-1,1\},$ and if $j,k\in\Bbb Z$ such that $f_n(j)=f_n(k),$ then $j=k.$ (That is, $f_n$ is injective.)
- If $n\in\{-1,1\},$ and if $k\in\Bbb Z,$ then there is some $j\in\Bbb Z$ such that $f_n(j)=k.$ (That is, $f_n$ is surjective.)

It turns out that $f_n$ is a homomorphism *regardless* of our choice of $n\in\Bbb Z,$ and is injective for all $n\in\Bbb Z$ *except for* $n=0.$ As you've determined, however, $f_n$ is surjective if and only if $n\in\{-1,1\}.$

To show this, you should use the fact that $(\Bbb Z,+)$ is a *cyclic* group, generated by $1$ or $-1,$ but nothing else. A homomorphic image of a cyclic group will again be cyclic, generated by the element to which its generator is mapped--in this case, $f_n(1).$ In particular, the image of $f_n$ will be a cyclic subgroup of $(\Bbb Z,+).$ In order to be all of $\Bbb Z,$ however, $f_n(1)$ must be one of the two generators of $(\Bbb Z,+).$

Comment: no, I want to show that -1 and 1 are the only ones that do it, not that -1,1 do it, this is clear to me. Of course the problem is, that for $n \neq -1,1$ this map is not surjective, but I don't see how to show this without using the fact that the set is ordered or by using the rationals.

Comment: I, too, misread your question. My apologies! I have updated my answer.

Comment: How can you show, for example, that $f_2$ is not injective? (Not just with the group structure, but by any means.)

Comment: sorry, I meant of course not surjective. Well, I would need to show that nothing maps to 1.

Comment: Ah! There we go. Now that I have a better grasp of your predicament, let me update my answer once more.

Comment: Well I think you just restated the question why does $nx=1 \rightarrow n \in \{-1,1\}$ to why can $n$ for $|n| \neq 1$ not be a generator of the integers, which of course one would also argue by using monotony arguments or anything like that.

Comment: How are the integers defined for you?

Comment: well, we defined the naturals and then used equivalence relations to define the integers.

Comment: How were the naturals defined, then?

Comment: ah now i see, this boils down to a generator. thank you, I believe you know :-).

Comment: Excellent! Let me know if you run into any more trouble with the proof, or even if you'd just like me to double-check it for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Consider the composition of $f_n$ with $g_m\colon {\bf Z}\to {\bf Z}/m{\bf Z}$ for various natural $m\geq 2$. Conclude that $f_n$ is not onto for $n\notin \{-1,1\}$.